# Assigning file data to array of structs

Tags: c++, struct, getline

I'm currently attempting to assign a line of data from an input file to an array of structs.

Here is my struct:

```
struct student
    {
        int ID;
        int hours;
        float GPA;
    };

    student sStudents[MAX_STUDENTS]; // MAX_STUDENTS = 10
```

Where:

```
for (int i = 0; !inputFile.eof(); i++)
{
    getline(inputFile, dataLine);
    cout << dataLine << endl; // Everything outputs perfectly, so I know dataLine is getting the correct information from getline()
            //??
}
```

After an hour of crawling through Google I still don't have an idea of how to get my getline() data into each struct array.

I have tried,

```
sStudents[i] = dataLine;
sStudents[i] << dataLine;
sStudents.ID = dataLine;
```

Here is my data file:

```
1234  31  2.95
9999  45  3.82
2327  60  3.60
2951  68  3.1
5555  98  3.25
1111  120 2.23
2222  29  4.0
```

At this point I've become frustrated and I'm just not sure what to do. I'm convinced at this point I'm going about it completely incorrectly but not sure how to continue from here. I know that 10 elements of sStudents exist so that's good but how can I get the values from the input file into each .ID, .hours, .GPA? Perhaps getline() is being used incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
int ID = 0;
int hours = 0;
float GPA = 0.0;
int i = 0;
ifstream inputFile("data.txt");
while (inputFile >> ID >> hours >> GPA)
{
   sStudents[i].ID = ID;
   sStudents[i].hours = hours;
   sStudents[i].GPA = GPA;
   i ++;
}
```

Comment: I'm frustrated that I didn't even consider multiple ">>". Thank you

Comment: @Legato It is OK, I did not know that when I first learned to use >> and ifstream too.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion using the Standard Library.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

// your data structure
struct Student {
  int id;
  int hours;
  float gpa;
};

// overload the input stream operator
bool operator>>(std::istream& is, Student& s) {
  return(is>>s.id>>s.hours>>s.gpa);
}

// not necessary (but useful) to overload the output stream operator
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& s) {
  os<<s.id<<", "<<s.hours<<", "<<s.gpa;
  return os;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // a vector to store all students
  std::vector<Student> students;
  // the "current" (just-read) student
  Student student;

  { // a scope to ensure that fp closes                                     
    std::ifstream fp(argv[1], std::ios::in);    

    while(fp>>student) {
      students.push_back(student);
    }
  }

  // now all the students are in the vector
  for(auto s:students) {               
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is beyond my ability at this time, and it is my fault for not stating that earlier. Thank you anyways bud

Comment: Patience - you will get there; take it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

To get data out of an input stream use the `>>` operator. So:

```
int i;
file >> i;
```

extracts a single integer from the file. By default it is space delimited. Use that and see if you get further.